# How to increase the file limit of GitHub Actions?

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration, gatsby, github-actions

I have the follwing error:

`Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/  runner/work...`

I tried all ways to increase the limit (like ulimit -S -n unlimited, sysctl, etc) but seems to not work, neither with sudo

screnshot [image]

My website has a lot of markdown files (~ 80k) used by gatsby to build the final .htmls.

On my machine I need to increase the file limit, of couse, then works. But in the github actions I can't figure out a way to do this.

My github action `workflow.yml`

```
    name: Build

    on: [push, repository_dispatch]

    jobs:
    update:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v1

        - name: Increase file limit
            run: sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536

        - name: Debug
            run: ulimit -a

        - name: Set Node.js
            uses: actions/setup-node@master
            with:
            node-version: 12.x

        - name: Install dependencies
            run: npm install

        - name: Build
            run: npm run build
```

I think this could be related to this issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17321

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like these GitHub/Expo issues might be the problem:

> https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action/issues/20
>
> **ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached**
>
> https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/277
>
> **Handle ENOSPC error (fs.inotify.max_user_watches reached)**
>
> Thanks for testing!
>
> I'm afraid this seems to be a GitHub Action
>   limitation. That docker image is forcing the
>   fs.inotify.max_user_watches limit to 524288, but apparently GHA is
>   overwriting this back to 8192. You can see this happen in a fork of
>   your repo (when we are done, I'll remove the fork ofc, let me know if
>   you want to have it removed earlier).

Continuing...

> Yes, it's related to a limitation of the environment you are running
>   Expo CLI in. The metro bundler requires a high amount of listeners
>   apparently. This fails if the host environment is limiting this. So
>   technically its an environment issue, but I'm not sure if the CLI can
>   change anything about this.
>
> I find the limit in GitHub Action personally a little low. Like I
>   tried to outline in an earlier comment on that CLI issue, the
>   limitation in other CI vendors is actually set to the default max
>   listeners. Why they did not do this in GH Actions is unclear, that's
>   what I try to find out. Might be a configurational issue on their
>   hands, or an intentional limitation.

... And ...

> So, there exists a fix, that seemed to work for me when I tried. What
>   I did was to follow this guys tip: “Increasing the number of
>   watchers” — @JNYBGR https://link.medium.com/9Zbt3B4pM0
>
> I then did this in my main action.yml With all the specifics
>   underneath the dev release
>
> ```
> steps:
>  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
>  - name: Setup kernel for react native, increase watchers
>       run: echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
>  - name: Run dev release fastlane inside docker action
> ```

Please let us know if any of this matches your environment/scenario, and if you find a viable workaround.

---

UPDATE:

The OP tried `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` in his .yaml, and now Gatsby is failing with `Error: EMFILE: too many open files open '/home/runner/work/virtualizedfy.gatsby`, and NodeJS subsequently crashes with an assertion error:

```
node[3007]: ../src/spawn_sync.cc:460:v8:Maybe<bool> node:SycProcessRunner::TryInitializeAndRunLoop(v8:Local<v8::Value>): Assertion `{uv_loop_init(vu_loop_ == (0)' failed.
```

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:

> https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/12011
>
> Google seems to suggest https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs as
>   a drop in replacement for fs, I might also experiment with that to see
>   if it makes a difference.
>
> EDIT: I can confirm that monkeypatching fs with graceful-fs at the top
>   of gatsby-node.js as in the snippet below fixes the issue for me.
>
> ```
> const realFs = require('fs')
> const gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs')
> gracefulFs.gracefulify(realFs)
> ```
>
> EDIT2: Actually after upgrading from Node 10 to Node 11 everything
>   seems to be fine without having to patch fs... So all is well!

Comment: No, it sounds like the problem has "moved".  Based on your additional information, also try my suggestion above.

Comment: I will try your sugestion, fyi I'm using node 12. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I did some progress. But now it falling on: https://pastebin.com/raw/F8RfvvnC

Comment: I'm using google cloud build in parallel, seems to be working (still building...)